# How do I model bind in asp.net mvc 3 to an already created instance?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to get model binding to work with an existing object. I'm pretty new to MVC so forgive me if the approach is bad.

We have a large patient object. The process is, the patient is first loaded, stored in the session, then edited across multiple pages. We don't want to create a new instance every time model binding occurs because only a subset of properties have been edited. The patient lives in a temporary state until a hard save occurs and then the patient is saved to the database.

I'm trying to take advantage of model binding in asp.net mvc 3, but realized that a new instance is created each time it occurs.

I'm not certain how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Jeffrey to go for a custom model binder but instead of implementing `IModelBinder` I would inherit from the `DefaultModelBinder` class and only override the `CreateModel` method.

The `CreateModel` method is the one that instantiates new instances of Model classes every time so in that method I would check if the session has patient instance and if yes I would return that.

```
  public class CustomModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder
  {
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.Type modelType)
    {
      // check if the session has patient instance and if yes return that.

      return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
  }
```

After registering this model binder then I would specify the action methods what are the properties needs to be included for update the Model using the `Bind` attribute.

Ex.

```
public ActionResult UpdatePatientNameOnly(Patient patient[Bind(Include="First, Last")])
{
}

public ActionResult UpdatePatientAge(Patient patient[Bind(Include="Age")])
{    
}
```

**Important**: I haven't tested this

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, I create a custom model binder like so:

```
public class PatientModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var patientId = int.Parse(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("patientId").AttemptedValue);

        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        Patient patient;

        //Add logic to search session for the right patient here.

        return patient;
    }
}
```

Then, you can wire up the ModelBinder in Application_Start method of your global.asax file using the following line:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Patient), new PatientModelBinder());
```

Then, any of your actions that take in a patientId will get a hyrdrated object of Patient pulled from the Session.

Comment: Do I simply need to return the correct patient and then it will bind to that patient? Or, are there steps in-between?

Comment: This will override the default model binder, so you will need to rebind the properties that the default ModelBinder would use.

Comment: I would suggest to inherit the model binder from DefaultModelBinder and override the CreateModel method. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TryUpdateModel to bind data from Request.Form to an existing object.
Something like this:

```
ActionResult SomeControllerAction()
{
    var model = Session["Model"]; // get object from model
    if(!TryUpdateModel(model))
       //return validation
    else
       // do something
}
```